# Java JTable - Make only one column editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I was wondering how to make one column of a JTable editable, the other columns have to be non editable.

I have overwritten isCellEditable() but this changes every cell to non editable.
Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 34):

you can set if is `isEditable` for `TableColumn` or `TableColumn and TableCell` too

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
     switch (col) {
         case 0:
         case 1:
             return true;
         default:
             return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: wrong - a) there is no method isEditable anywhere b) TableColumn has no notion of editability at all c) TableCell does not exist. Correct would be _isCellEditable_ either on the TableModel implemenation or on JTable  - -1 for sloppiness

Answer (score 21):

Override the [table model](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

`isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` takes two arguments, just return true for the column you want?

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
return columnIndex == 0; //Or whatever column index you want to be editable
}
```

Comment: It is `columnIndex == 0` not `rowIndex == 0`

Answer (score 11):

this would set editable true for column 3 and 8 and false for others .

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {

            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                    false, false, true, false, false,false,false, true
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit[columnIndex];
            }
};
```

Comment: Thx @arash, good piece of code. I have slightly modified to disable the particular cell, using the following code... **'@Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex == 1){
           return false;}
    return canEdit[columnIndex];
            }'** ... may this useful to disable particular cell.

Answer (score 6):

JXTable/TableColumnExt of the SwingX project have api to configure editability per-table and per-column

```
 // make the table completely read-only
 xTable.setEditable(false);
 // make a column read-only
 xTable.getColumnExt(index).setEditable(false);
```

Note that it is only possible to narrow the editability compared to that returned by model.isCellEditable. That is you can make a editable cell read-only but not the other way round

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a class which extends `JTable` and add a boolean array

```
public class MyTable extends JTable {
    private Boolean[] editable_columns;

    public DetailsTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames) {
        super(rowData, columnNames);
        editable_columns = new Boolean[columnNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++){
            editable_columns[i] = true;
        }
    }
```

Create your own method to modify the value for one column

```
public void setColumnEditable(int index, boolean isEditable){
        if (index > -1 && index < editable_columns.length){
            editable_columns[index] = isEditable;
        }
    }
```

And after Override `setValueAt` with your boolean array

```
@Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
        if (editable_columns[column])
            super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Reading the remark of Kleopatra (his 2nd time he suggested to have a look at [javax.swing.JXTable](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTable.html), and now I Am sorry I didn't have a look the first time :) ) I suggest you follow the link

I searched for an asnwer, and I combined several answers to my own solution: (however, not safe for all solutions, but understandable and quick impelmented, although I recommende to look at the link above)

You can keep it more flexible to set which column is editable or not later on, I used this for exmaple:

```
    columnsEditable=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    table=new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(){

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                if(columnsEditable.isEmpty()){
                    return false;
                }
                if(columnsEditable.contains(new Integer(col))){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
          }
    });
```

And I used this function to set editable or not:

```
public void setColumnEditable(int columnIndex,boolean editable){
    if(editable){
        if(!columnsEditable.contains(new Integer(columnIndex))){
            columnsEditable.add(new Integer(columnIndex));
        }
    }else{
        if(columnsEditable.contains(new Integer(columnIndex))){
            columnsEditable.remove(new Integer(columnIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

Note: of course you have to define columnsEditable and JTable table global in this class:

```
private JTable table;
private ArrayList<Integer> columnsEditable;
```

Note 2: by default all columns are not editable, but that is my desired behaviour. If you whish otherwhise, either add all columns to columnsEditable or change the behaviour completely (make ArrayList columnsNonEditable in stead).
In regard to Kleopatra's remark: its better not to use this last suggestion (but it depends on the used tablemodel and what you do in the rest of your program).

Comment: not a safe solution: the view _must_ respect the model's setting, so whatever you implement on the view level can only narrow the editabilty of the model, never widen it. So somewhere in your code you must first query the model, and only if that returns true, keep or change that decision

Comment: Ok, thanks for that feedback, but that can be implemented easily I think. It's more I wanted more flexibilty than hardcoding the column which is editable. But it's a good thing to think over, changing the colmns will change this, however I normally set: table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false) (for example)

Comment: @kleopatra: thinking over it, your comment also depends on what you use as a tablemodel. The default tablemodel is always editable, so setting the editabilty will only narrow it, never widen. Besides my solution only expends the possibilities of the other given solutions.

Comment: you must not assume anything about the model ... even a DefaultTableModel might be extended to not allow editing ;-) Have a look at the source code of JXTable/TableColumnExt to get an idea of how to implement a safe (narrowing) logic

Comment: Ok, you convinced me, hte solution suggested worked for a simple case for me. However looking at JXTable, this gives a lot more possibilities!