# How to make table row uneditable but at the same time selectable in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I want to make my Jtable not editable, but at the same time i want it to be selectable. I tried by unchecking the 'enable' function in Jtables property, However this property restricted be from selecting any rows in my table. Is there anyway you can fix this?

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372799/making-jtable-cells-uneditable ?

Comment: Hey Andre,
I am actually new to java and in our class our teacher has not sought us to code each and everything in swing. He rather uses the drag and drop method. I did look at link you sent me but could not find where exactly should i be keeping that code. Do let me know.

Comment: `He rather uses the drag and drop method` -  means nothing to us. We have no idea what tool you are using. How to customize generated code will be different for every IDE. Ask your teacher how to override a method of a generated component.  This is I recommend you don't use the IDE. The code generated can only be maintained on that IDE. On the other hand code you right can be maintained anywhere. Look at the examples found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for code you can download and modify.

Comment: Currently we are using NetBeans