# Make a column non-editable in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, tablecolumn

I created a `MasterDetail Simple Form` using `Netbeans`, and I have a `JTable` which is related to the database.

I want to edit a column in this `JTable` to make it non-editable.

I Googled about it and this all I can find :

```
this.masterTable.getColumn("Validation").setEditable(false);
```

which won't work with me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JTable - Make only one column editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167173/java-jtable-make-only-one-column-editable)

Answer (score 12):

Override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the TableModel.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...)
{
    @Override 
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        // add your code here
    }
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Comment: I can't override the isCellEditable(...) method, because my object extends the JTable class directly.

Comment: i have used it but my cell is still editable, i have write inside isCellEditable return column==4 but all cells in the table are still editable, why?

Comment: @mautrok I just edited the code. There was a typo. The class should return "boolean" not "Boolean". Maybe that is the problem. If not I can't help because I can't guess what your code looks like. If you need more help then ask a question and post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Disabling user edits on JTable for multiple columns

```
JTable table = new JTable(10, 4) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return column == 3 || column==4 || column==5 ? true : false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution using GUI :

- Right-click on the table cells.
- From popup menu, choose "Table Contents..".
- Uncheck the editable check box for the column you want to make it
  non-editable.

[image]

Comment: Don't use `GUI Editors` for UI building you cannot learn much. Instead code it yourself.

Comment: @Amarnath why reinvent the wheel ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution if you are extending JTable directly:(place this code in constructor)

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames){

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
        {
            // make read only fields except column 0,13,14
            return column == 0 || column == 13 || column == 14;
        }
    };
```

this.setModel(tableModel);

Answer (score 1):

```
isCellEditable()
```

Here is the Javadoc: [isCellEditable(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29)
is the method you want. If you are using a TableModel then this method can then be overridden in the subclass of the TableModel for that JTable instance.

Comment: I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the jtable name is wordListJTable:

```
        String colTitles[] = {"#", "Word", "Definiton"};
        boolean[] isEditable = {false,true,true};
        wordTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(colTitles, 0) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                // make read only fields except column 0,13,14
                return isEditable[column];
            }
        };
        // The 0 argument is number rows. 
        wordListJTable.setModel(wordTableModel);
```