# How to make only one column of JTable non-editable

Tags: java, jtable

I am using JTable in my Java program, and I want to make only one column of JTable **non-editable**. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JTable - Make only one column editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167173/java-jtable-make-only-one-column-editable)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to extend upon `DefaultTableModel` so that you have your own implementation of it, and from there in the `isEditable()` function, you would have a condition that checks to see whether the cell should be editable or not.

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
{
    //If you didn't want the first column to be editable
    if(col == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Refer to [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) on how to work with tables, it has some really good information regarding working with an extension of DefaultTableModel.