# Making a JTABLE column uneditable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I named my JTable tblList and I wanted a certain column to be not-editable. I have found the below code that should do the job however, i cannot for the life of me make it work on my existing table. I guess my question in particular is, how do I call the below codes to be set on my existing table named tblList?

```
JTable model = new JTable(){

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        return column==3 false;
    };
};
```

Comment: That won't compile. Will it return "column==3" (true) or "false" (false). Try "return column==3 ? false : true;"

Comment: Or just `return column != 3;`.

Comment: I've seen that too but how do I directly apply it to my existing jtable? When I use the codes I've posted, it seems to me that it's making a new table and it leaves my existing JTable the same way it is. 

Please bear with me for I'm still is a newbie when it comes to this. Thanks!

Comment: @joppiealiw The functionality you're looking for is defined by the `TableModel`, you should never have the need extend a `JTable` to implement this function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JTable - Make only one column editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167173/java-jtable-make-only-one-column-editable)

Answer (score 2):

The way of doing this would be to have your own `TableModel` and override the `public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex);`. As a rule of thumb, we should not override a `JTable` method. For your reference, this is what JTable does - delegates the call to the data model:

```
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return getModel().isCellEditable(convertRowIndexToModel(row),
                                         convertColumnIndexToModel(column));
    }
```

The way we do it is:
Step 1: Create a Table model:

```
public class SimpleTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    @Override
    boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        // Your logic goes here
    }
}
```

Step 2: Pass an instance of this class to the constructor of `JTable`

```
JTable table = new JTable (new SimpleTableModel());
```

Please find a working example below (this is not the way I usually write code and nor should you but just to give you an example):

```
    static class Table extends JFrame {
        public Table() {
            String[] columns = new String[] {
                "Id", "Name", "Hourly Rate", "Part Time"
            };

            //actual data for the table in a 2d array
            Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
                {1, "John", 40.0, false },
                {2, "Rambo", 70.0, false },
                {3, "Zorro", 60.0, true },
            };

            TableModel m = new AbstractTableModel() {

                @Override
                public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                    return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                }

                @Override
                public int getRowCount() {
                    return data.length;
                }

                @Override
                public int getColumnCount() {
                    return data[0].length;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable (int row, int col) {
                    return false;
                }

            };

            //create table with data
            JTable table = new JTable(m);

            //add the table to the frame
            this.add(new JScrollPane(table));

            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would love to tell you I quite understand what you just said but I understand little of it.  I feel like I gotta inject the name of my JTable (tblList) there somewhere but then again, you folks know better than me. I appreciate your response though. I'll see what I can do to understand it further.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) that could be helpful

Comment: @joppiealiw Swing uses a form of [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), meaning the model is seperated from the view, you should be able to take your model and apply it to different instances of `JTable` (or apply multiple models to a single instance of `JTable`) and have it work as expected

Comment: funny enough, I tried the below codes and ran it in debug mode, the program executed it but it still leaves the columns editable. I went and check the "ancestor mode". and it shows "return true;" 


 public class SimpleTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{




  @Override




  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){




  return false;


  }

  }